# How to deserialize stream to object using System.Text.Json APIs

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

I'm receiving a response from a web api call as a stream and need to deserialize it to a model.

This is a generic method, so I can't say which parts of code will use this and what's the response payload.

Here's the method:

```
public async Task<T> InvokeAsync<T>(string method)
{
    Stream response = await this.httpClientWrapper.InvokeAsync(method);
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    using var streamReader = new StreamReader(response);
    using var reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader);
    return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
}
```

I'm trying to remove Newtonsoft and use [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.0) API.

I found this [porting guide](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/61024c30b966ee63c357a491370a2daf94c4c42f/src/System.Text.Json/porting_guide/README.md) in corefx repo in Github, where section [Reading from a Stream/String](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/61024c30b966ee63c357a491370a2daf94c4c42f/src/System.Text.Json/porting_guide/README.md#reading-from-a-string--stream) states:

> We currently (as of .NET Core 3.0 preview 2) do not have a convenient
> API to read JSON from a stream directly (either synchronously or
> asynchronously). For synchronous reading (especially of small
> payloads), you could read the JSON payload till the end of the stream
> into a byte array and pass that into the reader

So following this advise I come up with the following:

```
public async Task<T> InvokeAsync<T>(string method)
{
    Stream response = await this.httpClientWrapper.InvokeAsync(method);
    var length = response.Length;
    var buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent((int)length);
    var memory = new Memory<byte>(buffer);
    await response.WriteAsync(memory);
    var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(memory.Span);
    ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
    return result;
}
```

So my question is - did I understand the advise correctly and this is the way to go ?

This implementation probably can be improved on many aspects, but what bothers me most is renting the byte array from the pool e.g. `Stream.Length` is a long and I convert it to int which can cause `OverflowException`.

I tried to look into [System.IO.Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/) and use `ReadOnlySequence<byte>` overloads of JSON API, but it gets very complicated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I believe that documentation needs to be updated because .NET Core 3 has a [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasync?view=netcore-3.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_DeserializeAsync__1_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) to read from a stream directly. Using it is straight-forward, assuming the stream is encoded in UTF8:

```
private static readonly JsonSerializerOptions Options = new JsonSerializerOptions();

private static async Task<T> Deserialize<T>(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(contentStream, Options);
    return result;
}
```

One thing to watch out for is that by default HttpClient will buffer the response content in-memory before returning unless you set the HttpCompletionOption to ResponseHeadersRead when invoking SendAsync:

```
var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, token);
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I saw later this API, though now I'm questioning what about bigger payloads. Chopping up entire stream and reading in buffers is done by `JsonTextReader`. Doesn't seem to be the case with `System.Text.Json` API, but that's another question.

Comment: Hi @Mike, did you find a solution for the bigger payloads?

Comment: @DirkBoer not sure which .NET Core version you're using, but in our case we're on .NET Core 3.1 & the implementation of `DeserializeAsync` from stream takes care of [chopping up the stream to buffers and reading from them](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Read.Stream.cs#L89).

Answer (score 4):

Starting from ASP.NET Core 6 you should use *DeserializeAsyncEnumerable()* method:

```cs
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/api/products");
request.SetBrowserResponseStreamingEnabled(true); // Enable response streaming
using var response = await Http.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
IAsyncEnumerable<Product?> products = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<Product>(stream, new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
       PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
       DefaultBufferSize = 128
     });

 await foreach (Product? product in products)
 {
   // ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Great point re DeserializeAsEnumerable. The only minor thing is the request.SetBrowserResponseStreamingEnabled method is part of the webAssembly/Blazor project, and the question relates to a Web API project (so sending request from the server)

Comment: I get an error in my deserialized object with this method! 
(Id = 12, Status = Faulted, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}")